# Appium pressKeyCode generate IME action

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium, android-softkeyboard, ime

In Appium release 1.8.1 the said it can generate IME actions.
[Appium 1.8.1 Release](https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-1-8-1-release/22162)

How can I generate IME event enter with action ID 5 / Create action Done or Next.

Also is it possible to fire it via ADB?

I know I can fire the command adb shell input  keyevent 66 to get enter event. What I want is to add to this command actionId.

Answer (score 3):

This is unit test written by Appium for generating IMEAction.

This test is written for APIDemos.apk which can be found [here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/ApiDemos-debug.apk)

```
public class KeyCodeTest {

  final By PRESS_RESULT_VIEW = By.id("io.appium.android.apis:id/text");
  final Activity activity;   

    @Test
    public void pressKeyAndGenerateIMEActionTest() {
        activity = new Activity(driver.getCurrentPackage(), ".text.KeyEventText");
        driver.startActivity(activity);
        driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent()
                .withKey(AndroidKey.ENTER)
                .withFlag(KeyEventFlag.SOFT_KEYBOARD)
                .withFlag(KeyEventFlag.KEEP_TOUCH_MODE)
                .withFlag(KeyEventFlag.EDITOR_ACTION));
        final String state = driver.findElement(PRESS_RESULT_VIEW).getText();
        // This event won't update the view
        assertTrue(state.isEmpty());
    }
```

I believe if we can run this, it should show adb command details in appium server logs
The definition of different KeyEventFlag can be read [here](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/nativekey/KeyEventFlag.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.pressKeyCode(int key, Integer metastate)` to generate IME actions.

Key codes can be found here: `io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidKeyCode`

Make sure you're using UIAutomator2 by doing `desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");`

To do it via adb you could run a shell command or use appium's relaxed security (run your appium with CL arg `--relaxed-security`) and `mobile: shell` command.

Eg: `driver.executeScript("mobile:shell", "adb shell input keyevent 66");`

Here's a full example:

```
@Test
public void testKeyEvent() {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.your.app.package");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".your.Activity");

    AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    // Press enter
    driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);

    // Press Editor action
    driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION);

    // Send adb command
    driver.executeScript("mobile:shell", "adb shell input keyevent 66");

    // Switch ime using adb shell
    driver.executeScript("mobile:shell", "adb shell ime set 5");
}
```